# CriteriaBuilder and or condition is not applying required/proper parenthesis

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am new this board. I tried to find solution but could not find solution. In case it is available please share me that.

```
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<DmdInventory> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ItemInventory.class);
    Root<ItemInventory> itemRoot = criteriaQuery.from(ItemInventory.class);

    Predicate first = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("margin"), 1.0);
    first = criteriaBuilder.and(first, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("costWithoutExpense"), 1.0));
    first = criteriaBuilder.and(first, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("markup"), 1.0));

    Predicate second = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("lastImportCost"), 2.0));
    second = criteriaBuilder.and(second, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("expenses"), 2.0));
    second = criteriaBuilder.and(second, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("profit"), 2.0));

    Predicate third = criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("totalCost"), 2.0));
    third = criteriaBuilder.and(third, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("cost"), 2.0));
    third = criteriaBuilder.and(third, criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("quantity"), 2.0));
    Predicate allPredicate[] = { first, second, third };
    Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(allPredicate);

    criteriaQuery.where(finalPredicate);
    List<ItemInventory> items = this.entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Current result

```
 select * from
    item_nventory inven 
where
    inven.last_import_cost=2.0 
    and inven.expenses=2.0 
    and inven.profit=2.0 
    or inven.total_cost=2.0 
    and inven.cost=2.0 
    and inven.quantity=2 
    or inven.margin=1.0 
    and inven.cost_without_expense=1.0 
    and inven.markup=1.0
```

Expected result

```
  select * from 
    item_nventory inven 
where
     inven.last_import_cost=2.0 
and inven.expenses=2.0 
and inven.profit=2.0 
or (inven.total_cost=2.0 
and inven.cost=2.0 
and inven.quantity=2 ) 
or (inven.margin=1.0 
and inven.cost_without_expense=1.0 
and inven.markup=1.0)
```

My final requirement will be something like below

```
 select * from 
    item_nventory inven 
where
    inven.last_import_cost=2.0 
and inven.expenses=2.0 
and inven.profit=2.0 
or ((inven.total_cost=2.0 
and inven.cost=2.0 
and inven.quantity=2 ) or (inven.quantity_on_hand>0))
or (inven.margin=1.0 
and inven.cost_without_expense=1.0 
and inven.markup=1.0)
```

Please help out me in this.

Comment: Could you please provide a full stack trace of your error.

Comment: i am not getting any error. i provided by code of my method apart from last line which is return statement. SQL generated while running code . AT same time i also provide what i am looking as output.

Comment: It looks like you have a typo in your `Expected result`: under `... and inven.profit=2.0 ( or (inven.total_cost=2.0 ... ` your mean `... and inven.profit=2.0 or (inven.total_cost=2.0 ... `? And the same in the `final requirement`?

Comment: @SternK thanks for letting me know my typo. I corrected SQL. I hope requirement will be clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I think, problem is in gradual contruction of predicates. Try contruction below.

```
Predicate firstA = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("margin"), 1.0);
Predicate firstB = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("costWithoutExpense"), 1.0);
Predicate firstC = criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("markup"), 1.0);
Predicate first = criteriaBuilder.and(firstA, firstB, firstC);

 . . .

Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(first, second, third);
```

Or alternative solution with list - easy to add or remove another predicates (event dynamically)

```
List<Predicate> allPredList = new LinkedList<>();
{
  List<Predicate> firstPredList = new LinkedList<>();
  firstPredList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("margin"), 1.0));
  firstPredList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("costWithoutExpense"), 1.0));
  firstPredList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(itemRoot.get("markup"), 1.0));
  allPredList.add(criteriaBuilder.and(firstPredList.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
}

 . . .

Predicate finalPredicate = criteriaBuilder.or(allPredList.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
```

Comment: Did you find a solution, having the same problem here?